# Move files up one directory in Linux / OSX

Tags: shell

I'm currently going through this tutorial: https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/appendix-a-cli/ex11.html Even after going over it, I couldn't figure out how to move a file up one directory.

I'm currently in `testdirectory1`.

I created a subdirectory `subd3`.

I successfully moved a file called `testfile1copy.py` into `subd3` via `mv file1copy.py subd3/`

Now, how do I move that file back to `testdirectory1`?

Comment: You can access parent directory with `..`. So it becomes `mv filefullpath` ..`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv subd3/file1copy.py .
```

`.` references the current directory.  If `$PWD` is the full path of `testdirectory1` (some shells will automatically set that variable for you), you could also do:

```
mv "$PWD/subd3/file1copy.py" "$PWD"
```